# Implementing java mouse listeners, custom gui

Tags: java, user-interface, lwjgl, mouselistener, slick2d

I'm working on a game currently using slick2d + lwjgl and I am trying to implement listeners for the gui components. I was wondering on how to do that since I am currently stumped. I was thinking I could do something like this

GuiComponent class....

```
public void addListener(MouseAdapter e){
   // Stuck on this part
}
```

Than implement it into a menu like this

```
gComponent.addListener(new MouseAdapter(){

   @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            // listener logic

        }
}
```

I don't know how to actually trigger the method mouseClicked inside the addListener method, because when i ran it like this nothing happened unless I am delusional. Anyway, any help does help even if you just send me to a javadoc or something like that. Thanks guys & merry christmas :)

EDIT:

GuiComponent class

```
package com.connorbrezinsky.turbulent.gui;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;

public class GuiComponent {

int x, y, width, height;

Color color;
Image i;

public GuiComponent(Gui gui, int _x, int _y, int w, int h, Color c) {
    gui.components.add(this);
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
    color = c;
}

public GuiComponent(int _x, int _y, int w, int h, Color c) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
    color = c;
}

public GuiComponent(Gui gui, int _x, int _y, int w, int h) {
    gui.components.add(this);
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
    color = Color.white;
}

public GuiComponent(int _x, int _y, int w, int h) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
    color = Color.white;
}

public void addText(String s){

}

public void addSprite(Image s){
    i = s;
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    if(i == null) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }else{
        i.draw(x,y,width,height);
    }
}

public void addListener(MouseAdapter e){
    // stuck here
}
```

}

Example in menu class

```
GuiComponent guiTest = new GuiComponent(20, 20, 50, 10);

public void update(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, int arg2)    throws SlickException{
  guiTest.addListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("click");
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: You don't have code in there, so of course you won't know! Add something like `System.out.println("Hey! Don't click me there!");`

Comment: I did try that, but I'll check again @liquidsystem

Comment: From what you said on my (now deleted) answer, I'm not sure why you're using your own component, where the awt/swing components would work (assuming) just as well/if not better than the one you're writing. The code for such stuff as adding a listener is more difficult than just making a method and plopping something in it.

Comment: @liquidsystem my edits made above and I'm making my own because I'm using lwjgl made with slick and implement awt/swing into it would't work too well I pressume.

Answer (score 1):

Slick2D offers [several components](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/class-use/MouseListener.html#org.newdawn.slick.gui), I don't know if you've seen them. Maybe can you use the [AbstractComponent](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/gui/AbstractComponent.html), by inherits from it to do what you expect. It seems to provide the `addListeners` method that you want to implement by yourself. It say simplify you own code.

Then to add a listener, you can use your gameContainer. Through `gc.getInput().addListener()`.

With your code it would be something like :

GuiComponent guiTest = new GuiComponent(20, 20, 50, 10);

```
public void update(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, int arg2)    throws SlickException{
  arg0.getInput().addListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("click");
        }
    });
 }
```